# Disable all CPLEX cuts using the Python API

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am using Cplex 12.8 to solve a MIP and I want to test the performance of a cut I am programming and comparing it to the measures used in a paper. To do it I need to turn off all Cplex cuts, but I cannot find the way to do it.

I have found some answers for other languages, but I am unable to find the homologous response for python. 
Can someone indicate me how to do it, or where to look for it in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

In Cplex, cuts can be turned off (or increased), but setting [parameters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.5.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/cuts/41_params.html#User_manual.uss_solveMIP.672903__title1310474232097).  There are parameters for each class of cuts.  You can turn off the individual category of cuts by setting the appropriate parameter to -1.  You can also turn all cuts off by setting [CutsFactor](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.5.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/CutsFactor.html) to 0.  Cplex Parameters can be set on the "context.cplex_parameter" property on the [Model](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc/master/docs/mp/docplex.mp.model.html) object, or in the call to solve.